# Using l1 magic toolbox for compressive sensing : Positive definite matricies.

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, signal-processing

I'm trying to use l1 magic to reconstruct an image from a single pixel camera I've developed. The test functions used are random binary patterns projected onto the object scene, so each pattern is represented as a row vector of 0's and 1's and form the rows of the test function matrix phi. 
ie.

```
 b = phi.x = phi.psi.alpha
```

where b is a column vector of measurements (from a photodiode), phi is a matrix with rows representing the projected binary patterns (of 0's and 1's), and x represents a column vector of the image. x is deconstructed into psi (a transform matrix) and column vector alpha (representing the image).

The equation is to be solved with the condition that the l1 norm of alpha is minimised (i.e. it's sparse)

However, the matrix phi is not positive definite, so the basis persuit function throws out an error. This is confusing me as most of the literature promotes using random test functions. Is there something wrong here? Do you have to ensure your "random" test functions eventually form a positive definite matrix?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If the *columns* of $\Phi$ represent the projected binary patterns, then shouldn't you have $b=\Phi^Tx$ and not $b=\Phi x$? ...Also you probably want to minimize the $L^1$ norm of $\alpha$, not $x$. I don't think positive definiteness should have anything to do with it because the matrices aren't square in the first place so can't possibly be positive definite.

Comment: Each row of phi represents the binary patterns, so yes it's the same thing.
And you are indeed correct, I'm trying to minimise the l1 norm of alpha (which is used to construct x later), apologies for both of those the errors in the post! I'll edit those in, thanks.

Hmm that's interesting, since undersampling pretty much means always having rectangular test matricies. It seems to be a requirement in the optimisation function, but I guess it can't since it shouldn't be expecting square matricies.

Any ideas on why it might be spitting out this error?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using $\ell_1$-magic in particular? Why not just start with a more general modeling framework so you can try exactly the models you want?

Comment: I'd suggest trying [SPGL1](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mpf/spgl1/) instead.